# Modern/introductory books on partition relations/partition calculus?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, large-cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

Are there any modern books on partition relations for cardinals/the partition calculus? I've seen several sources say it's a very active field of infinitary combinatorics, but the only book on it I can find is Erdős' original Partition Relations For Cardinals. I don't know if it's just me, but I found it to be a rather difficult read. Are there any other introductory books on the partition calculus, that possibly reflect the state of modern research?

Comment: see Wikipedia: Infinitary combinatorics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_combinatorics)